# json.dumps() encodes StrEnum with custom __new__ to empty string

Tags: python, json, serialization, enums

I have an enum similar to the following:

```py
from enum import Enum


class Currencies(str, Enum):
    EURO = ("EUR", True)
    YEN = ("JPY", False)

    supports_decimals: bool

    def __new__(cls, value: str, supports_decimals: bool):
        obj = super().__new__(cls)
        obj._value_ = value
        setattr(obj, "supports_decimals", supports_decimals)

        return obj
```

This allows things like:

```py
>>> Currencies.EURO.value
'EUR'
>>> Currencies.EURO.supports_decimals
True
>>> f"{Currencies.EURO}"
'EUR'
```

However:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(Currencies.EUR)
'""'
```

This would work if my enum had simple string members instead of tuples, but instead it results in empty strings, and since the enum's members are seen as `str`, a custom encoder class doesn't call `.default()` on them at all, so I can't define a custom encoding for them.

The problem likely comes down to `str.encode()`, because indeed:

```py
>>> Currencies.EUR.encode()
b''
```

But even knowing that, I don't know how I could instruct `json.dumps()` to use the member's `_value_`. I tried overriding `encode()` and that makes `Currencies.EUR.encode()` work, but `json.dumps()` still returns an empty string.

Note that I'd rather keep the enum a `str, Enum` because turning it into a simple Enum would complicate other parts of my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your enum instances *are empty strings*. `obj = super().__new__(cls)` makes an instance that is an empty string.

Make a nonempty string:

```
obj = super().__new__(cls, value)
```